# Oil may have been slightly contaminated on last change ... change again?

Tags: engine, oil

Long story short (details are irrelevant ... and embarrassing), I may have introduced some atmospheric contamination in my recent oil change.  Basically, small dust and dirt flecks, that sort of debris.  I only realized this after I started the my car with the new oil.

Everything seems to be running fine, but I'm quite paranoid about something eventually causing damage.

Would that have been caught by the filter?  Is there any harm (other than to my wallet) in changing it immediately again?

Comment: If you've run it already, the damage is done and the contaminants will be trapped by the oil filter.

Comment: I agree with cory here ... though I doubt much damage would be done. The filter is going to catch anything which you'd be able to see. The only thing which would take punishment (in most engines) is the oil pump, but I doubt much would have occurred. Still, the filter will clean the stuff out.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2: isn't the pump located "downstream" from the filter?  ie.: if the filter caught it, it would have caught it *before* it reached the pump, no?

Comment: Not in most cases. Usually oil flows from the pickup to the pump, then it's first stop is the filter. From there it goes out to the rest of the engine (can go anywhere depending on how the engine oil flow is engineered).

Comment: Depends on opportunity cost.

Comment: @danny117: I'm not sure what you mean by this.  The cost to redo the oil change is negligible for me.

Comment: Opportunity cost is a measurement of your time and how much you would make doing something else.

Comment: @danny117: well worth the time and money for my peace of mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, change your oil again, but most importantly the filter. If there were significant contaminants in the oil then they will likely have been trapped by the oil filter, and if there's enough contaminants the filter could get prematurely filled. Changing the filter means changing your oil.

Comment: Yes, by "changing", I always mean oil **and** filter.

Comment: That was more for the world at large's benefit @RecoveringNerdaholic.

Comment: fair enough, just wanted to clarify what I meant.